# My terminal shows an error "Dart_LoadScriptFromKernel: The binary program does not contain 'main'."

Tags: dart, class

```
import 'dart:io';

class Area {
  double calculateCircleArea(double r) {
    double area = 3.14 * r * r;
    return area;
  }
}

class Myclass extends Area {
  Area ar = new Area();

  @override
  double calculateCircleArea(double r) {
    double area = 3.14 * r * r;
    print(area);
    return area;
  }

  static void main(List<String> args) {
    Myclass mc = new Myclass();
    print("Enter the radius");
    double rad = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    print("Area of the circle is");
    mc.calculateCircleArea(rad);
  }
}
```

Here is my code. I am a newbie on this platform. Please support me.

I tried to run this code in dartpad. But it shows an error `"No main method found"`

I tried to run it in Terminal:

```
dart Myclass.dart
```

But same error.

Answer (score 0):

Dart is not like Java where everything needs to be inside classes including the main method. Instead, Dart allows for global methods and variables. And it also require the `main()` method to be a global method with that name.

So your program needs to be rewritten a bit. I have done it like the following:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

class Area {
  double calculateCircleArea(double r) {
    double area = 3.14 * r * r;
    return area;
  }
}

class MyClass extends Area {
  Area ar = Area();

  @override
  double calculateCircleArea(double r) {
    double area = 3.14 * r * r;
    print(area);
    return area;
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  MyClass mc = MyClass();

  print("Enter the radius");
  double rad = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

  print("Area of the circle is");
  mc.calculateCircleArea(rad);
}
```

*Bonus: You don't need to use the `new` keyword in Dart and is therefore not often used.*

Comment: @AKHILJAMES No problem. If you find my answer acceptable, please click "accept" on it so your question can be closed.